# Why use Ruby on Rails i18n if you are only going to specify english locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seen Ruby on Rails applications that use the `i18n` gem to call translations in their views, but the applications *only* have an `en.yml` file - that is they only specify one locale, the default locale. I guess this has some utility in that you can re-use string values and only have to specify the definition once (perhaps especially convenient for date formats), but, it does seem to me to defeat the point of using `i18n` in that other locales should be there with translations of each key.

My question is, is using `i18n` this way a standard Rails convention? Am I missing something that setting up an application this way provides?

Comment: Certainly it isn't. https://dev.to is a great dev community built on ruby on rails. Their code quality is quite good and it's open source but they don't use i18n whatsoever.

Comment: I would argue that using I18n even when you do not plan to actually translate your application might have the advantage that you separate your view code from your copy. That might make it easier and less error-prone for non-technical people to change texts on a website. And there are tools around that allow handling these locale files.

Comment: @spickermann Additionally, i18n/l10n is one of those things that's easy if you do it right from the beginning but often a major undertaking if you try to add it later. Using the i18n gem costs very little if you're only using one locale but saves a lot of pain and suffering when you inevitably discover that the world is bigger than your own back yard.

Comment: my experience with this is a recent project that was required to be translatable into multiple languages... so naturally Rails I18n. But after 3 years it's still English-only. It was over-specified at the start. This comes at a cost, it's a point of friction working against rapid dev. The locale files need to be rationally organized, without duplication. I curse every time I have to go find the locale file for the view I'm working on. My project has been used in the Pacific Islands and in Africa... always English-only. There may be scenarios that must have I18n, but that's not my experience,.

Comment: In my opinion, with i18n, it requires almost no extra work to build english-only website, but it saves a lot of time to alter the project to support multiple languages in the future, so why not?

Comment: So these are all really good comments that I'd gladly upvote as answers fwiw

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that `i18n` is a standard Rails convention. Basically, that is a good practice because you never know will you need additional languages for your app. If that happens some time in the future, you have an easy way of translating your whole app. Also, for me personally, I don't like to see embedded translations inside controllers or views. It's much cleaner with `i18n`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. `i18n` is definitely a standard Rails convention, that's not really my question, my question is: is using it this specific way a convention. Also, "I don't like to see embedded translations inside controllers or views." I don't understand what this is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is an opinionated framework, so everything that it ships with can be considered it's convention. However, it's certainly a weaker convention than several other parts of the application, and you are free to use the I18n library or not, depending of your needs.

I would compare this convention with, for example, shipping minitest as default: it's something the framework is imposing on you, but to a lesser degree. They intentionally keep the library as small as possible to not impact applications which don't use it, and to also allow for customization. This intent can be seen in [this footnote in the official documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#footnote-3-ref)

---

I have debated the *"to use or not to use"* with colleagues several times.

One argument in favor, as was pointed out in the comments, is that it keeps all the text in your application grouped together, providing organization and allowing for non-tech people to edit it more easily. And if you do need translations, it's already been engineered for you.

The main anti-use-scenario: applications which are country-bound or language-bound, where using translations is just plain YAGNI (You ain't gonna need it principle). Having to `t.('gigantic.wall.of.text)` when it could be simple changed to an 'OK' drives me bananas.

God forbid too, if some clever devs find out that they can get away with not using translations in their reviews: now there's no consistency in the system and your efforts to centralize your application's texts has gone south.

---

As everything with software development, it's a matter of using the right tool for the right job. Don't be afraid to discard entire parts of the framework if you don't need it - especially because it encourages you to do that (you can skip views, tests, or the entire active-record for example, at project creation).

*Be the framework's master, not it's slave.*